# Java, reference variables that point to the same object in the memory

Tags: java, variables, memory, user-interface

I'm developing a GUI program, where I have made classes, that cluster ActionListeners, by functionality. My question is regarding how the JVM handles jButtons, that has the same ActionListener added to them.

First; I am aware that the JVM can save memory, by letting two reference variables that point to an identical string (for instance), point to the same string object in the memory.

```
public class Example {
    String str1 = "SomeString";
    String str2 = "SomeString";  
}
```

Now, my question is this: If I have, say, 5 jButtons. All buttons have the same ActionListener added to them. When the program is run, will they have 5 seperate, identical, instaces of the same class added to them? Or will the JVM do something similar (to the above mentioned) ?

- Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If you show us what you're doing we can tell you what will happen. Or you can test it out for yourself. Your question is confusing - if you pass the same ActionListener object to five different buttons, why would you think it would split into five objects?

Comment: Thanks for your response. In my example, I meant; if I explicitly add five different object to five different buttons - will the JVM optimize memory space, and let them share the same object.

Comment: In that case, no. The JVM does not merge objects like that. Strings are a special case. You could, however, use the same ActionListener for multiple buttons.

Comment: Thanks a lot! that perfectly answer my question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it really depends on how you created the `ActionListeners`.  If you did

```
button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    ....
});
....
button5.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    ....
});
```

Or

```
ActionListener al= new ActionListener() {
    ....
};
button1.addActionListener(al);
....
button5.addActionListener(al);
```

In the first case you, true, have 5 different action listeners.  But in the second you have only one.  When can you have only one?  When it does exactly the same and on the same objects.

Comment: The first would be separate objects, and the second would be the same object, correct?

Comment: Thanks for answering.
I have been doing what you mention in your first example - and now that you mention the last example, Im surprised I didn't do that.

But as shown in my question example; my thoughts was mainly whether the JVM could pick up, that a number of jButtons have been given identical objects, and hence let them then share the same.

Comment: That's a very good question.  And the answer is not easy.  Perhaps just not smart enough?  Leaving some work for us to do?

Answer (score 3):

It depends.

This will give them the same instance.

```
ActionListener al = new ActionListener() { ... };
button.addActionListener(al);
button2.addActionListener(al);
...
```

while this will give them their own.

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { ... });
button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { ... });
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe it would pass the same ActionListener object to all 5 buttons.
If you want to know the truth, I suggest you test it for yourself